# C - Print value stored at symbol location

Tags: c, linux, ld, ld-preload, nm

I have a simple command line application (custom `dir` binary) which I would like to instrument. The debug symbols are enabled, and I can see the global string pointer I'm interested in, `the_full_path_name` in the output of `objdump` and `nm -D`.

Is it possible, in [c](/questions/tagged/c), to somehow lookup that symbol name/location, and print the contents of the memory which it points at using code injection (ie: `LD_PRELOAD` library with a custom `gcc attribute((constructor))` and additional functions)? I need to accomplish this without having to attach `gdb` to the process.

Thank you.

Comment: C does not support introspection. But if you know the variable, you can simply `printf("%d", the_var)` (for other than `int` use different conversion type specifiers).

Comment: From what I understand, this should be possible through `LD_PRELOAD`. Have you tried to import the symbol using the global declaration `extern char *the_full_path_name;` (or whatever its exact type is) and then printing it?

Comment: Did you compile the program with `-rdynamic`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure if i understood your question but does following help you anyways?

File containing global pointer

```
$ cat global.c     
char mylongstring[] = "myname is nulled pointer";

$ gcc -fPIC -shared global.c -o libglobal.so
```

Original library

```
$ cat get_orig.c 
#include <stdio.h>    
extern char * mylongstring;
char *get()
{
  mylongstring = "get from orig";
  return mylongstring;
}

$ gcc -fPIC  -shared  get_orig.c -o libget_orig.so -L. -lglobal
```

Fake Library

```
$ cat get_dup.c 
#include <stdio.h>
extern char * mylongstring;
char *get()
{
  mylongstring = "get from dup";
  return mylongstring;
}

$ gcc -fPIC  -shared  get_dup.c -o libget_dup.so -L. -lglobal
```

Actual consumer of global variable:

```
$ cat printglobal.c 
#include <stdio.h>

char *get();

int main(void)
{
 printf("global value=%s\n",get());
 return 0;
}
$ gcc printglobal.c -L. -lglobal -lget_orig -o a.out
```

otool output

```
$ otool -L a.out 
a.out:
        libglobal.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        libget_orig.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

Running `a.out`

```
$ DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=./ ./a.out                                                                                                                                                           
global value=get from orig
```

Replace library

```
$ cp /tmp/libget_dup.so libget_orig.so 
$ DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=./ ./a.out
global value=get from dup
```

BTW, i tested this on MAC so `.so` is really a misnomer for `.dylib`